# Enforce deferring controller logic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, eslint

We are trying to apply the guidelines listed in John Papa's [AngularJS Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide).

One of the rules which we started to follow is [Defer Controller Logic](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#defer-controller-logic):

> Defer logic in a controller by delegating to services and factories.
>
> Why?: Logic may be reused by multiple controllers when placed within a
>   service and exposed via a function.
>
> Why?: Logic in a service can more easily be isolated in a unit test,
>   while the calling logic in the controller can be easily mocked.
>
> Why?: Removes dependencies and hides implementation details from the
>   controller.

This is something we've violated in the past by putting data retrieval logic into controllers instead of isolating it in a service.

Now I'd like to make the rule as strict as possible. Ideally, I would like angular to throw an error if one of the configured services is passed as a dependency to a controller. Is it something that can be solved on the angular level, or I should try solving it separately - for example, statically with a custom `ESlint` rule?

Would appreciate any insights or hints.

---

In particular, the following controller violates the rule, because it uses [`$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) directly:

```
function OrderController($http, $q, config, userInfo) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.checkCredit = checkCredit;
    vm.isCreditOk;

    function checkCredit() {
        var settings = {};

        return $http.get(settings)
            .then(function(data) {
               vm.isCreditOk = vm.total <= maxRemainingAmount;
            })
            .catch(function(error) {

            });
    };
}
```

<sup>Also, let me know if I'm getting overly concerned/crazy about the code quality :)</sup>

Comment: I would try using ESLint and use a rule which prevents using $http/$resource in your controllers. I personally think you should just talk amongst your development team and just have everyone on the same page when dealing with data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPD (june 2015): [`eslint-plugin-angular`](https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular) has built-in [`ng_no_services`](https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular/blob/master/rules/ng_no_services.js) rule that enforces the deferring controller logic to services or factories.

---

Old answer.

Here is the [`ESLint` custom rule](http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules.html) that restricts a function, which name ends with `Controller` or `Ctrl`, to have any of the configured arguments passed in:

```
module.exports = function (context) {

    "use strict";

    var restrictedParams = context.options[0] || [];

    var check = function (node) {
        var name = node.id && node.id.name;

        if (/(Controller|Ctrl)$/.test(name) && node.params) {
            var params = node.params.map(
                function (param) {
                    return param.name;
                }
            );

            restrictedParams.filter(function (n) {
                if (params.indexOf(n) != -1) {
                    context.report(node, "This controller function uses a restricted dependency {{param}}.", {
                        param: n
                    });
                }
            });

        }
    };

    return {
        "FunctionDeclaration": check,
        "FunctionExpression": check
    }
};
```

Example configuration (`eslint.json`):

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jasmine": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "angular": true,
    "browser": true,
    "element": true,
    "by": false,
    "inject": false
  },
  "plugins": [
    "angularjs"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "ctrl-logic": [2, ["$http"]]
  }
}
```

Now, imagine I have the following controller defined (violating the rule):

```
angular
    .module("app")
    .controller("AppController", AppController);


AppController.$inject = ["$scope", "ConnectionService", "ConfigService", "StatusService", "$http"];

function AppController($scope, ConnectionService, ConfigService, StatusService, $http) {
    ...
}
```

If I run `eslint` check it would report the error:

```
$ grunt lint
Running "eslint:target" (eslint) task

app/app-controller.js
  8:0  error  This controller function uses a restricted dependency $http  ctrl-logic

✖ 1 problem
```

---

I can imagine there are ways to define the dependencies in a way that this particular rule would not spot the violation, but, if you follow the advices suggested in the style guide, it should work for you (works for me).

Answer (score 2):

I have written a kind of workaround but it so tricky and dirty that it must not ever be used:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="violation in codestyleViolations">
            {{violation}}
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []).config(function($controllerProvider) { 
        $controllerProvider.$get[0] = 'trickyInjector';
    }).factory('trickyInjector', ['$injector', '$rootScope', function($injector, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.codestyleViolations = [];
        var originalFunc = $injector.invoke;
        $injector.invoke = function(fn, self, locals, serviceName) {
            if (locals && locals.$scope && fn.indexOf('$http') !== -1) {
                $rootScope.codestyleViolations.push('ALYARM! ' + serviceName + ' uses $http');
            }
            return originalFunc.apply(this, arguments);
        };
        return $injector;
    }]).controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    }]);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I like your "must not ever be used" :D Thank you!